# Script To Export All DTS Packages ON IS To File System

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Is there a script that will export all DTS packages on an Integration Services Server to one file system path (ie: C:\DTSPackages)?  Currently, the task of right clicking, selecting export, choosing the file system seems somewhat redundant if a script exists, yet all I've found are scripts to show what packages exist (unimportant).

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify, are you talking about DTS or SSIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the DTUTIL utility to script movement of packages:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162820.aspx

Here is an example of moving from SQL to File:

[http://www.bimonkey.com/2010/01/ssis-command-line-utilities-part-1-dtutil](https://web.archive.org/web/20180605061200/http://www.bimonkey.com/2010/01/ssis-command-line-utilities-part-1-dtutil/)

Here are some scripts to enumerate packages in MSDB:

http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2010/01/10/list-all-ssis-packages-deployed-on-your-integration-server/

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-all-SSIS-packages-3b247394

Finally, there's a SQL query you can run to generate the dtutil calls which you can then pipe into a batch file. See [ssis package extract from msdb](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/11/ssis-package-extract-from-msdb.html)

If you want some help sticking it all together let me know. I don't make much effort here unless I know the OP is engaged.

Comment: I run a query to build the appropriate dtutil calls [ssis package extract from msdb](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/11/ssis-package-extract-from-msdb.html)

Comment: @billinkc you should post as an answer as it is a good deal more useful than mine.

Comment: @billinkc Awesome code; I have it generated, now can I save the results and have the DTUTIL load the saved file and then save each item (so that I can avoid manually doing each line by line)?

Comment: Nevermind, I just saved it as a script.bat and loaded it through CMD.  Thanks @billinkc!  Incredibly awesome and useful script!