# Exporting SSIS project from SQL Server catalog

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to export an SSIS project from the Integration Services Catalog and am getting an error:

> The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server Authentication. Start the operation with an account that uses Windows Authentication. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 27123)

I am connected to SQL Server using SQL Authentication and the sys admin account. I don't have a login with which to use Windows Authentication.  How can I export the project and packages to my local drive?

Answer (score 0):

**Right Way**

You can use [DTUtil Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162820.aspx) to perform these operation.

You can found helpful information at the following Links:

- [Script To Export All DTS Packages ON IS To File System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309263/script-to-export-all-dts-packages-on-is-to-file-system)
- http://www.bimonkey.com/2010/01/ssis-command-line-utilities-part-1-dtutil/

**Workaround**

I know this is not the right way, this is a workaround:

1. Open a new Integration services project in visual studio
2. On the solution explorer tab add an existing package from sql server using your sql authentication